# URL change when link was click

Tags: javascript

why is my url wont change every time i click my link? here's my code.

```
function myFunctionD(id) {var x=document.getElementById(id);   
  document.getElementById('t_id').value=x.id;
  var myURL = "http://www.sample.php";
  document.location = myURL + "?id=" + x.id ;

    }

<a href="docview.php?id=26" id="3" onclick="myFunctionD('3')" target="iframe_a" >
July 17, 2013</a>
<a href="docview.php?id=26" id="3" onclick="myFunctionD('4')" target="iframe_a" >July 18,   2013</a>
```

whats wrong with my code? thanks

Comment: Could you also add the element that has the id `t_id`? Also, you have two elements with the same `id` attribute - the `id` needs to be unique.

Comment: var x=document.getElementById(id);  document.getElementById('t_id').value=x.id; error starts here itself

Comment: anyone know how to avoid refreshing the page when the url is change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two element with the same id = 3. ID must be unique!

Answer (score 0):

In the **href** of each anchor **docview.php?id=26** the id is the same please check the id must be changed. ex like **docview.php?id=27** and you are taking the query string value of **id** and then respective file you are showing..